# Euclidean Cluster Detect - Parameter description

Tags: ros, lidar, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering where I can find any documentation on lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect package developed in autowre. I can get it work just fine but I would like to read any publications about it as I am dealing with specific parameters now, any papers etc.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342427/euclidean-cluster-detect---parameter-description/) by [cassini.huygens](https://answers.ros.org/users/42910/cassini.huygens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2020-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the README in the folder for the package (https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/core_perception/tree/master/lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect). Each package *should* (but does not always) have a README similar to this one.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassini.huygens](https://answers.ros.org/users/42910/cassini.huygens/) on 2020-01-27**:
Thanks, I was looking more for the theory behind it e.g. publications. the ReadMe seems to be informative for parameters only.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-01-31**:
@cassini.hyugens - The README also includes a "References" section which describes the PCL functions that are used and their theory of operation.